# Inserting two figures with two captions in one column

Tags: floats, ieeetran

Using `IEEEtran` package, I want to place two figures with two captions (one right one left) in a column. A layout like this

```
----------------------------    ----------------------------
----------------------------    ----------------------------
----------------------------    
----------------------------     *********     **********
----------------------------     *********     **********
----------------------------     *********     **********
----------------------------     *********     **********
----------------------------     *********     **********
----------------------------     caption1       caption2
----------------------------    
----------------------------    ----------------------------
----------------------------    ----------------------------
```

When I search for that, the results mostly explain about "how to put a wide figure on two columns".

current code which stack the figures is listed below

```
\begin{figure}[!h]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.6\textwidth]{figs1.eps}
    \caption{caption1}
    \label{f1}
\end{figure}  

\begin{figure}[!h]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.6\textwidth]{figs2.eps}
    \caption{caption2}
    \label{f2}
\end{figure}
```

What is the solution then?

**UPDATE**

After applying the method in the answer, the width of caption2 exceeds the column width. I used the codes that I understood from the answer. Please let me where did I made the mistake

```
\begin{figure}[!h]
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.5\linewidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=1\textwidth]{figs1.eps}
    \caption{caption1}
    \label{f1}
\end{minipage}
\hspace{0.1cm}
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.5\linewidth} 
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=1\textwidth]{figs2.eps}
    \caption{caption2}
    \label{f2}
\end{minipage}        
\end{figure}
```

[image]

Comment: Regarding the code in the follow-up posting: First, you shouldn't set the widths of the `minipage`s to exactly  `0.5\columnwidth`; choose something like `0.45\columnwidth` instead. Second, don't use a fixed amount of spacing between the minipages *unless* you really intend to exceed the width of the column. Instead of `\hspace{0.1cm}`, use `\hspace{\fill}`. Finally, do omit the `\centering` instructions: They're redundant since the graphs are being set to the full widths of the minipages.

Comment: You didn't follow exactly my code... That's why you have the caption exceedind the column.

Comment: Yes... but I now understand :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can insert two `minipage`s inside a single `figure` environment.

```
\documentclass{IEEEtran}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1-8]

\begin{figure}[htbp]
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.45\linewidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{figs1.eps}
    \caption{caption1}
    \label{f1}
\end{minipage}%
    \hfill%
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.45\linewidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{figs2.eps}
    \caption{caption2}
    \label{f2}
\end{minipage} 
\end{figure}

\lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You may want to mention what should be done if the two figures should, in fact, be allowed to "float".

Comment: @Mico BTW: I take this opportunity to congratulate you for your 100k reputation... Bravo!

Comment: Many thanks -- I truly appreciate these best wishes!! I look forward to extending these wishes to you when you cross the mark as well!

Comment: Excuse me, what is the purpose of `lipsum`? I didn't use that. Instead I use `\hspace{0.1cm}`. Moreover, the length of caption2 exceeds the column width.

Comment: @mahmood `lipsum` and the `\lipsum` command are just to typeset dummy text.

Comment: @mahmood Add `[t]` optional argument to `minipage` as in the edited answer.

Comment: Didn't work.... I will update the post with a picture